# If statements inside else if

Tags: java

This might be a very basic question, but please can someone respond to this? Is it okay to use if statements inside else if? Is this allowed?

```
if(conditionA)) {
        //do A stuff
    }
    else if(conditionB)) {
        if(conditionB1)
            //do B1
        if(conditionB2)
            //do B2
        if(conditionB3)
            //do B3
    }
```

Comment: Just for wonder why wouldn't it be?

Comment: "shows little research effort"

Comment: I know this is only pseudo-code, but man those extra closing parentheses are bugging the heck outta me!

Comment: @KevinL I think the OP ask about good practice, not if it is allowed in the Java syntax

Comment: @morgano If that's the case, then OP should re-word the question. `Is it okay to use [...]?` is ambiguous as to whether its about allowed syntax or best practices, but `Is this allowed?` immediately after essentially clarifies the ambiguity to be about allowed syntax, which is something either easily searched for or tested in a short program (both of which are a kind of research).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not only OK; I'd even recommend it, especially if `conditionB` is relatively expensive to evaluate. For instance, here's an alternative way:

```
if(conditionA) {
    //do A stuff
} else if(conditionB && conditionB1) {
    //do B1
} else if(conditionB && conditionB2) {
    //do B2
} else if(conditionB && conditionB3) {
    //do B3
}
```

Let's say that `conditionB` is evaluated by a method (like `boolean getConditionB() {...}`) and `getConditionB()` is expensive to execute. The JVM would have to execute your expensive method on every possibility, so your approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. For clarity in reading your own program, keep indentation consistent

```
if(conditionA) {
    //do A stuff
}
else if(conditionB) {
    if(conditionB1)
        //do B1
    if(conditionB2)
        //do B2
    if(conditionB3)
        //do B3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is perfectly fine. I would try to be consistent with your indentation and brace usage though.

```
if(conditionA)) {
    //do A stuff
} else if(conditionB)) {
    if(conditionB1) {
        //do B1
    }
    if(conditionB2) {
        //do B2
    }
    if(conditionB3) {
        //do B3
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try it to find out, but yes, nesting an if statement inside of an else if statement is fine.

Answer (score -1):

There are two kinds of the If Statement statement. The first is

```
if ( Expression ) Statement
```

and the second is

```
if ( Expression ) Statement else Statement
```

In place of the Statements in the form above you can use any statement. It lets make such constructions

```
if ( Expression ) Statement else if ( Expression ) Statement // and so on
```

Of course, you can use curly brackets

```
if ( Expression ) {
    Statement
} else if ( Expression ) {
    Statement
} else if ( Expression ) {
    Statement
} else if ( Expression ) {
    Statement
} else if ( Expression ) {
    Statement
} // end so on
```

Comment: I'll be honest; I'm not quite sure what you're getting at here. Can you please edit your question to clarify it? Also, you can do code formatting by highlighting the desired text, then clicking on the curly braces above the question text.